# What's a word that means the same as "tumbleweed in a desert" symbolizes?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a word that adequately describes the same context as invoked by tumbleweed rolling through a desert?

E.g. when someone tells a really bad joke and there is an awkward silence.

Comment: ... crickets ...

Comment: Why not just *awkward* as you mentioned? Another word I can think of is [*toe-curling*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/toe-curling).

Comment: Thanks @iterums, but it's not quite right. Perhaps there is no word for this?

Comment: Tumbleweeds are _rootless_.

Comment: Related(?): [Where to use the word “tumbleweed”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/122286/43980)

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you are asking for.  Are you saying the awkward silence after someone tells a bad joke can be attributed to its not finding a home in the minds of the listeners?  You know, just as a tumbleweed has no home or resting place.

Comment: Is this a word that is intended for written or spoken purposes? For written purposes, apart from ‘crickets’ as eminently suggested by @ThePhoton, another option would be quite simply: “…”, i.e., no words at all, just demonstrative silence in the form of an ellipsis. If it’s meant to be spoken, a demonstrative silence would be enough.

Comment: Are you only interested in the “awkward silence” sense of the tumbleweed metaphor? The same metaphor is used for some other contexts like a bad party or empty restaurant. Are you interested in something that can express that too?

Comment: Similar question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334781/is-there-an-idiom-or-typical-expression-for-an-unfunny-joke/335507#335507

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A joke that is unintentionally embarrassing which causes a prolonged moment of silence and stillness, when only the rustling sound of a tumbleweed can be heard.

[**Tumbleweed moment**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tumbleweed_moment) When a joke falls flat on its face, it can be called a tumbleweed moment.

A ***stony silence*** and ***deafening silence*** express the metaphoric meaning of tumbleweed.

Definition at [The free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deafening)

Comment: OMG completely forgotten about this answer and the question. I should have closed the more [recent question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334781/is-there-an-idiom-or-typical-expression-for-an-unfunny-joke?lq=1) as a duplicate of this one!  :)

Answer (score 0):

The image would more likely be that of tumbleweed rolling through a deserted town, creating an image of [desolation](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/desolate). Related to that is the concept of [moribund](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/moribund) as in a moribund sense of humour.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that there is a

> **Lurch** : an abrupt jerking, swaying, or tipping movement ; also : stagger

in the conversation, particularly as another usage ("— in the lurch") is

> in a vulnerable and unsupported position.

Considering a conversation is supposed to be comfortable and flow from one topic to the next, "lurch" suggests the opposite. It's just a very uncomfortable word.

*from m-w.com*

Answer (score -1):

Another possibility is Nomad:

> A member of a people who have no permanent abode and travel from place to place to
>   find fresh pasture for their livestock

from [here](https://www.google.ca/#bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&fp=e029c07b0bede007&q=nomad+definition).

Comment: This doesn't capture the “awkward silence” sense that the question is looking for.