# Can Tumbleweed be used to describe a tall, gangly, and clumsy person?

Tags: meaning, terminology, word-usage, nicknames

My friends and family call me Tumbleweed because I'm tall and clumsy, but sometimes I wander if there's more to it when my "friends" call me Tumbleweed. I was wandering if Tumbleweed can be used as a nickname for such a person (clumsy and gangly)?

Comment: I'm not sure how we can help determine what your friends and family mean by a nickname. Do you think they're all conspiring to demean you?

Comment: The actual plants are [rather noxious, as CGP Grey explains,](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=hsWr_JWTZss) but that isn't the association most people have with them.

Comment: [Related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/122286/191178).

Comment: Does sound like if your friends and family think Tumbleweed means tall and clumsy, then that is what works as a nickname. If you changed your mind about liking it, tell them you've changed your mind.

Comment: For me, "tumbleweed" evokes the image of  something that never stays very long in one place.